# Python setup.py: How to get find_packages() to identify packages in subdirectories

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, distutils

I'm trying to create a setup.py file where find_packages() recursively finds packages. In this example, `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` are all modules that I want to be installed and available on the python path. For example, I want to be able to do `import foo, bar, baz`.  The `bar-pack` and `foo-pack` are just regular non-python directories that will contain various support files/dirs (such as tests, READMEs, etc. specific to the respective module).

```
├── bar-pack
│   └── bar
│       └── __init__.py
├── baz
│   └── __init__.py
├── foo-pack
│   └── foo
│       └── __init__.py
├── setup.py
```

Then say that setup.py is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name="mypackage",
    version="0.1",
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

However, when I run `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py sdist`, only the `baz` directory is identified and packaged.

I can simplify it down further, and run the following command, but again, only `baz` is identified.

```
python -c "from setuptools import setup, find_packages; print(find_packages())"
['baz']
```

Do you know how I might extend the search path (or manually hard-code the search path) of the find_packages()?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Interestingly for me, folders that were not packaged into wheel are the folders that do not have `__init__.py` file. As soon as I placed the empty `__init__.py` file in the folder which needs to go into wheel, folders/files were rolled into wheel package.

Answer (score 49):

This is like using the [src-layout](https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging/) for the "foo" and "bar" packages, but the flat layout for "baz". It's possible, but requires some custom configuration in the `setup.py`.

Setuptools' `find_packages` supports a "where" keyword ([docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#using-find-or-find-packages)), you can use that.

```
setup(
    ...
    packages=(
        find_packages() +
        find_packages(where="./bar-pack") +
        find_packages(where="./foo-pack")
    ),
    ...
)
```

Since `find_packages` returns a plain old list, you could also just list your packages manually, and that's arguably easier / less magical.

```
setup(
    ...
    packages=["baz", "bar", "foo"],
    ...
)
```

The non-standard directory structure means you'll also want to specify the [`package_dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) structure for distutils, which describes where to put the *installed* package(s).

Piecing it all together:

```
setup(
    name="mypackage",
    version="0.1",
    packages=["baz", "bar", "foo"],
    package_dir={
        "": ".",
        "bar": "./bar-pack/bar",
        "foo": "./foo-pack/foo",
    },
)
```

The above installer will create this directory structure in site-packages:

```
.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
├── bar
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       └── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
├── baz
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       └── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
├── foo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       └── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
└── mypackage-0.1.dist-info
    ├── INSTALLER
    ├── METADATA
    ├── RECORD
    ├── REQUESTED
    ├── WHEEL
    ├── direct_url.json
    └── top_level.txt
```

Comment: Is it safe to say that the `where` and the `package_dir` pieces are both needed? When I tried specifying `find_packages() + find_packages(where="./bar-pack")` without the `package_dir` structure, pip coughed up an error `error: package directory 'bar-pack' does not exist`. I think you're right that just specifying the package names directly (avoiding `find_packages`) yields a more understandable solution.

Comment: @chrisinmtown Yes, I think they are both needed. One advantage of `find_packages` is that if you list packages manually it's easy to forget you need to add sub-packages - e.g. if there was a `bar/subbar/__init__.py`, you'd have to list both "bar" and "bar.subbar" as packages.

Answer (score -3):

You can also specify by ['packagea','packagea.*']

by this you wont be needed to specify sub packages as well.