# setuptools does not include any subpackages I specify

Tags: python, python-3.x, click, setuptools

I'm trying to create an installer for a CLI tool I'm developing with Click.  The problem is that for some reason submodules aren't included in the installer, which results in the following error:

```sh
from modules.commands import modules
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'
```

This is my directory structure:

```sh
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── app_config
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── configuration.py
│   └── commands
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── config
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── commands.py
│       ├── modules
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── commands.py
│       └── cli.py
└── tests
```

`cli.py` references commands created in `config` and `modules`.  When I'm running `cli.py` directly, it works fine. However, no matter what pattern I try for `setup.py` to include packages, the submodules in `commands` are not included.

This is the code for `setup.py`:

```py
setup(
    name='cli',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=find_packages(include=['src', 'src.*']),
    install_requires=[
        'Click'
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'cli = src.commands.cli:cli'
        ]
    }
)
```

I've checked the `find_packages`-implementation, but I can't see anything wrong with the way I've specified what is written above.  I've also tried hardcoding all packages, but that didn't work either. I've also tried with `src/*`, as maybe it uses full filepaths, but that didn't work either.

**Edit: More Troubleshooting**

Thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54430694/python-setup-py-how-to-get-find-packages-to-identify-packages-in-subdirectori), I tried running `python -c "from setuptools import setup, find_packages; print(find_packages('src'))"`.  According to the output, it finds all the submodules:

```
['app_config', 'commands', 'commands.config', 'commands.modules']
```

However, when I update my setup to include the same value, it fails.

setup.py:

```py
setup(
    name='cli',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    install_requires=[
        'Click'
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'cli = src.commands.cli:cli'
        ]
    }
)
```

Output:

```sh
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
...
      error: package directory 'app_config' does not exist
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: I had a problem like this when I hardcoded package names in setup.py. I needed to add the subpackages to to `packages` in `setup.py`

Answer (score 2):

you are probably missing `MANIFEST.in` file:

```
# https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/
graft src
global-exclude __pycache__
global-exclude *.py[cod]
```

and since you rely on `setuptools` as tool to build and distribute your package, it's  recommended to adopt the last best practises, `src` layout (the case) and move the config to `pyproject.toml` and `setup.cfg` files:

#### pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
# https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#setup-cfg-only-projects
requires = [
  "setuptools >= 40.9.0",
  "wheel"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

#### setup.py (optional)

```
from setuptools import setup

setup()
```

#### setup.cfg

```
# https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html
[metadata]
name = [..]
version = [..]
description = [..]
long_description = file: README.rst
long_description_content_type = text/x-rst
author = [..]
author_email = [..]
# maintainer =
# maintainer_email =
license = [..]
license_file = LICENSE
# license_files =
url = [..]
download_url = [..]
project_urls =
    Documentation = [..]
    Issue Tracker = [..]
    Source Code = [..]
keywords = [..]
sclassifiers =
    [..]
platforms = any

[options]
python_requires = >=3.6
install_requires =
    Click
packages = find_namespace:
package_dir =
    = src
include_package_data = True
zip_safe = False

[options.packages.find]
where = src

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    cli = commands.cli:cli  # Update: change `src.commands.cli:cli` to
                            # `commands.cli:cli` as per the comment below

[options.extras_require]
    [..]
```

if you are on windows and you want to build and publish your package

```
pip install build wheel twine
py -m build -n  # don't forget '-n' flage to force using your project venv
pip install -e .  # for editable mode 

# then, if everything is ok then pulish it on pypi
py -m twine upload dist/*
```

Comment: Thanks for the very verbose reply, really appreciate it.  Unfortunately that didn't work, as I receive the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`

Comment: my guess, try to remove `src` in `cli = src.commands.cli:cli` to be `cli = commands.cli:cli` and then try to rebuid your package, i hope that works, let me know

Comment: Stupid question, but how do I "run" this output?  I can see that it creates a tar.gz file, but it doesn't add a binary to ./venv/bin.  If I ran `pip install -e .`, it normally installs a binary in that directory, but I noticed it's now completely absent with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

I had exact same problem. Your question helped me find the answer from here:

- https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

I added `graft src` to my manifest.in
I changed (in setup.cfg under [options]) `packages = find:`
to `packages = find_namespace:`

Before I added graft I was super confused.
Then it could find my subpackage under my main in src