# pyproject.toml won't find project name with setuptools python -m build format

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

What is the correct format for supplying a name to a Python package in a `pyproject.toml`? Here's the `pyproject.toml` file:

```ini
[project]
name = "foobar"
version = "0.0.1"

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=40.8.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

A build called using `python -m build` results in the following error.

```
running check
warning: check: missing required meta-data: name, url
warning: check: missing meta-data: either (author and author_email) or (maintainer and maintainer_email) should be supplied
```

Based on [this reddit post question](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/qtul8g/problems_using_pyprojecttoml/) I had the same issue.

Comment: _setuptools_ does not accept the package info in `pyproject.toml`. Not yet. Either put this info in `setup.cfg`, or write a `setup.py`. -- Or switch to a different build back-end instead of setuptools, to one that reads package info in `pyproject.toml`, preferably one that is compatible with [PEP 621](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/).

Comment: hey, so, thanks! But also, can you please answer the question by giving an example of how a setup.cfg would be structured with a pyproject.toml to work with setuptools? And/or list the build backends that would work? And or give a date/issue which might be when this functionality could work?

Comment: you may refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71237291/12368419

Comment: Regarding PEP621 support in setuptools: https://discuss.python.org/t/help-testing-experimental-features-in-setuptools/13821 -- For the rest, including `setup.cfg` and a list of build back-ends that currently support PEP 621: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64151860

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Update***

At the time the question was asked, *setuptools* did not have support for writing its configuration in a `pyproject.toml` file ([*PEP 621*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/)). So it was not possible to answer the question.

Now and since its version 61.0.0, setuptools has support for PEP 621:

- https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html

---

***Original answer***

It seems that you are trying to write a [*PEP 621*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/)-style `pyproject.toml` with the *setuptools* build back-end.

But, as of now, *setuptools* does not have support for *PEP 621* yet. The work is ongoing:

- https://discuss.python.org/t/help-testing-experimental-features-in-setuptools/13821
- https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/tree/experimental/support-pyproject
- https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/search?q=621&type=issues

Until *PEP 621* support arrives in *setuptools*, one can:

- Use `setup.cfg`

  - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html
- Switch to a *PEP 621*-compatible build back-end instead of *setuptools*:

  - [*`pdm`*](https://pypi.org/project/pdm/)
  - [*`flit`*](https://pypi.org/project/flit/)
  - [*`trampolim`*](https://pypi.org/project/trampolim/)
  - [*`enscons`*](https://pypi.org/project/enscons/)
  - [*`whey`*](https://pypi.org/project/whey/)
  - probably more...

Comment: Currently exploring hatch and flit. Will update when I find a better alternative.

Comment: @polka In the meantime, _setuptools_ (in version `61.0.0`) added experimental support for _PEP 621_. This means you can put the whole packaging configuration in `pyproject.toml`, while still keeping _setuptools_ as your build back-end. It is experimental, as mentioned, but you could give it a try. See here: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html

Comment: This is a great answer. My project has dependency on python3.6 which is not supported by `setuptools>=61.0.0`. My solution was to use Flit for PEP 621-compliant builds, but the `setup.cfg` + `pyproject.toml` + `setuptools` suggestion should also work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu, then according to [this bug report](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3269#issuecomment-1254507377)

> On Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy) ensure the environment variable
> DEB_PYTHON_INSTALL_LAYOUT=deb_system before installing a PEP621
> compliant project with pip and setuptools.

That is, do *e.g.*:

```
DEB_PYTHON_INSTALL_LAYOUT=deb_system pip install .
```

instead of:

```
pip install .
```

Otherwise, the system may pick up the older version of `setuptools` (59.x) installed by apt even if you have upgraded `setuptools` in pip.