# Poetry package modulenotfound when installing a local package

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging, python-poetry

I am new to this packaging, and facing now a problem.
The problem is as follows. I have created a poetry project from the CLI:

```
 poetry new mypackage_test
```

and have a file structure as follows:

[image]

here both my **init**.py are empty

pyproject.toml

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "mypackage-test"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["my name <my@name.com>"]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{include = "mypackage_test"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

helloWorld.py

```
from pk1 import mypack


def helloworld():
    print("hello world")
    print(mypack.printMypk1())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    helloworld()
```

mypack.py

```
def printMypk1():
    print("in mypackage 1")
```

when I run this code eg.:

```
python helloWorld()
```

then it works as expected, but if i install this as a package and du this in python:

```
>>> from mypackage_test import helloWorld
```

i get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "C:\Programs\Python\Python3102\lib\site-packages\mypackage_test\helloWorld.py", line 1, in 
> from pk1 import mypack
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pk1'

am i doing this wrong? any suggestion ?

Note: if i unzip the ziped file in the dist folder then i can see that the files are packed/ziped as expected

Comment: can you try from .pk1 import mypack, you need to add (.)

Comment: i get this: "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Comment: I hope this link will help you, I think it's better idea to work with setup [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54430694/python-setup-py-how-to-get-find-packages-to-identify-packages-in-subdirectori](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54430694/python-setup-py-how-to-get-find-packages-to-identify-packages-in-subdirectori)

Comment: hmm getting the same error with setuptool... :(

Comment: Use absolute imports, always. In `mypackage_test/helloWorld.py`: `from mypackage_test.pk1 import mypack`.

Answer (score 1):

> Use absolute imports, always. In mypackage_test/helloWorld.py: from
> mypackage_test.pk1 import mypack. – sinoroc

thank you @sinoroc this helped